# Pulse Oximeter signal processing

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, dsp, pulse

I'm trying to make a pulse oximeter using IR Light,Red Led and a Light to frequency converter with [STM32L4 Controller](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/c5/ed/2f/60/aa/79/42/0b/DM00108832.pdf/files/DM00108832.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00108832.pdf) and Timer Input Capture. 
The  wavelength input of both the lights gives a similar graph as given below(when the finger is placed)  [image: Snapshot].
If the inputs are converted to frequency ,the graph that comes up is just the inverse of it(as f=1/l). 
I have referred many papers and once such is [given here](http://www.nxp.com/assets/documents/data/en/application-notes/AN4327.pdf),which shows a similar graph[Another Note](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa655/slaa655.pdf).
I had already tried with the frequency inputs that was giving correct heart rate but SPO2 values were between 82% and 86%.
The formula used is Percentage SPO2 = 110-25R.
where R = (RMS of RED/Average of Red)/(RMS IR/Average Red)

RMS values are calculated by multiplying 0.3535(1/2*sqrt(2)) with peak to peak value.

Am I following the correct method? if not how should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're near dead, your \$O_2\$ sats are not 86%.  Getting pulse out of a pulse-ox signal is dead easy, getting \$O_2\$ out is not.  In fact, while playing around with a Maxim pulse-ox unit, I couldn't even get Maxim to provide a formula unless I signed a non-disclosure with a waiver of liability.

This is fairly hard to calibrate.  I'd say assume your level is 99%, but how to get the other point on the low end without a full lab and blood gas testing is beyond me.

You might consider actually calculating the rms values instead of approximating.

Comment: Hi ,Thanks for your answer, I would consider calculating the RMS but which input must be taken,is it frequency inputs or wavelength inputs that must be used. I both the case it is the intensity of received light that is made use of and not the absorbed